# WPF Stopping ColorAnimation using RepeatBehavior

Tags: wpf, animation

I have some problems with stopping my animation, it just goes on forever. I would think that the RepeatBehavior should control this, but it does not seem to work.

```
<Grid.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Grid">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsNew}" Value="true">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation RepeatBehavior="1"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                To="LightGreen" Duration="0:0:0.25" AutoReverse="True" >
                            </ColorAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsNew}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Grid.Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is using

```
RepeatBehavior="1x"
```

So **1x** not just **1**, not very logical to me, but there probably is a reason..

Update (after input from @clemens):

According to MSDN the XAML Attribute Usage is:

```
<object property="iterationCountx"/>
- or -
<object property="[days.]hours:minutes:seconds[.fractionalSeconds]"/>
- or -
<object property="[days.]hours:minutes"/>
- or -
<object property="days"/>
- or -
<object property="Forever"/>
```

That makes a lot more sense, but not very intuitive..

```
<Grid.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Grid">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsNew}" Value="true">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation RepeatBehavior="1x"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                To="LightGreen" Duration="0:0:0.25" AutoReverse="True" >
                            </ColorAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsNew}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Grid.Style>
```

Comment: The reason is simple: `RepeatBehavior="1"` specifies *one day*, whereas `RepeatBehavior="1x"` specifies *one time*. You may want to take a look at the [RepeatBehavior documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.repeatbehavior.aspx).

Comment: @Clemens thank you for your input. I updated my answer and included the MSDN code.