# WPF TextBlock animation not firing when source is updated

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am simply trying to have some text flash red momentarily when the source for this TextBlock is updated. The text that the TextBlock is bound to works just fine, but for some reason the animation won't fire. I'm at a bit of a loss.

Any ideas?

```
            <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource Button.BackgroundBrush}"
                    Background="{StaticResource Screener.Background}"
                    BorderThickness="0,1,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AlertBoxMessage, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
                           Name="AlertBox"
                           MinHeight="55"
                           FontWeight="Normal"
                           FontSize="16"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Foreground="Black">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.SourceUpdated" >
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <ColorAnimation From="Black"
                                                    To="Red"
                                                    AutoReverse="True" 
                                                    RepeatBehavior="3"
                                                    Duration="0:0:2"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
```

Comment: try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499124/whats-the-difference-between-a-trigger-and-a-datatrigger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I think you misinterpreted the `Binding.SourceUpdated` event.

Each binding consists of two endpoints - a source and a target. The target is the object on which the binding is set, target property is the `DependencyProperty` whose value will be bound, the source is the object against which `Binding.Path` will be resolved, and source property is the property to which the target property is bound. In your case the target is the `TextBlock`, target property is `Text`, source is the (inherited) data context (a view-model I presume), and source property is `AlertBoxMessage`.

As you probably know bindings can work in several modes. `TwoWay` will allow updating in both source-to-target and target-to-source directions, whereas `OneWay` will only do source-to-target updates.

Key information here is that the `Binding.SourceUpdated` will be raised whenever a target-to-source transfer occurs (and `Binding.TargetUpdated` for source-to-target transfer, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.sourceupdated.aspx)). In your case however the value is always updated in source-to-target direction, because you set the binding mode to `OneWay`, so `Binding.SourceUpdated` is never raised. To achieve your goal you should use `Binding.TargetUpdated` event instead (with `Binding.NotifyOnTargetUpdated` set to `true`).

There are however several other issues with your code that will prevent it from working, so let's go over them:

1. You're trying to animate the `TextBlock.Foreground` property (of type `Brush`) with a `ColorAnimation`, which can only be used to animate a property of type `Color`, and you'll get an `InvalidOperationException`. You should set `StoryBoard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"`
2. It may seem a bit counter-intuitive but setting `RepeatBehavior="3"` will make the animation repeat for 3 days, and not 3 times (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381540/wpf-stopping-coloranimation-using-repeatbehavior)). You should use `RepeatBehavior="3x"`

To sum things up, here's the code that should do what you expect:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding AlertBoxMessage, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
           Name="AlertBox"
           MinHeight="55"
           FontWeight="Normal"
           FontSize="16"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           Foreground="Black">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color">
                            <ColorAnimation From="Black"
                                            To="Red"
                                            AutoReverse="True" 
                                            RepeatBehavior="3x"
                                            Duration="0:0:2"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your post was incredibly helpful. I'm just doing this for fun at this point, so I'm quite new at this. Sometimes I just code right past thinking whether I'm dealing with target/source or whether I want my binding mode oneway or onewaytosource. I also forget to consider brushes instead of colors, but at least I can figure that out...once it breaks.